# Should we allow questions related to specific, experiment-related technologies?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, site-scope, questions

I noticed [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/how-long-does-an-audiomoth-acoustic-logger-record-for), which has accumulated quite a few up and downvotes. My immediate thought was that it really doesn't have anything to do with biology and would be off-topic.

Having said that, we allow questions regarding laboratory techniques, for example, so why would questions about the technology required for other kind of field-based experiments be any different?

Are these posts on-topic or not?

Comment: I'll just initiate the response by saying : I don't think there's a 100% clear answer here. I hope many from the community weigh in! I would simply encourage anyone who is active on this meta post (whether reading, commenting, answering, or voting) to hold off final judgement until a couple of responses are given. You might be surprised by someone's response /rationale. (meta posts tend to receive slow response, so be patient)

Comment: A related question: [Do 0.2 vs 0.5 ml epitubes require different PCR machines, incubators, etc?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/107560/52196)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why that question would be off-topic. It's about a tool used in biological research. Not all biology happens in an enclosed lab in a building - sometimes your lab is an open field, or a coral reef, or a cave. We have a [lab-techniques](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-techniques) tag with [over 360 open questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blab-techniques%5D+closed%3Afalse) that are presumably on-topic, and the referenced question here is about a lab technique, albeit one related to a specific piece of equipment. This is no different in my mind than a question about next-gen sequencing, specifically related to using an Illumina sequencer and its output.